# Listing unicode words with same ending regular expression

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I am trying to list all the  Unicode words that has got one pattern using regular expressions. But it is not lsiting the words instead of that it delete the first part.
Here is my code

```
import re
string = ["മാണിയുടെ സംഭാഷണങ്ങള്‍ അടങ്ങിയ ","മന്ത്രിയുടെ സംഭാഷണങ്ങള്‍ അടങ്ങിയ", "ഉണ്ണിയുടെ സംഭാഷണങ്ങള്‍ അടങ്ങിയ ","രമേശ്യുടെ സംഭാഷണങ്ങള്‍ അടങ്ങിയ"]
print(type(string))
rePat = re.compile(u'[^യുടെ]',re.UNICODE)
print (rePat.sub("", str(string)))
```

The expected result is

```
മാണിയുടെ
മന്ത്രിയുടെ
ഉണ്ണിയുടെ
```

But 
I am getting `യുടെ` three times
What is the logical error here ?

Comment: Why isnt `രമേശ്യുടെ ` in the output. Even it contains `യുടെ`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) instead of replacing the string as

```
import re
string = ["മാണിയുടെ സംഭാഷണങ്ങള്‍ അടങ്ങിയ ","മന്ത്രിയുടെ സംഭാഷണങ്ങള്‍ അടങ്ങിയ", "ഉണ്ണിയുടെ സംഭാഷണങ്ങള്‍ അടങ്ങിയ ","രമേശ്യുടെ സംഭാഷണങ്ങള്‍ അടങ്ങിയ"]

rePat = re.compile(u'[^ ]+?യുടെ(?= |$)',re.UNICODE)
for st in string:
    print rePat.findall(st)[0]
```

will give output as

```
മാണിയുടെ
മന്ത്രിയുടെ
ഉണ്ണിയുടെ
രമേശ്യുടെ
```

**OR**

[`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.search) can also do the work for you

```
import re
string = ["മാണിയുടെ സംഭാഷണങ്ങള്‍ അടങ്ങിയ ","മന്ത്രിയുടെ സംഭാഷണങ്ങള്‍ അടങ്ങിയ", "ഉണ്ണിയുടെ സംഭാഷണങ്ങള്‍ അടങ്ങിയ ","രമേശ്യുടെ സംഭാഷണങ്ങള്‍ അടങ്ങിയ"]

rePat = re.compile(u'[^ ]+?യുടെ(?= |$)',re.UNICODE)
for st in string:
    print rePat.search(st).group()
```

Gives as

```
മാണിയുടെ
മന്ത്രിയുടെ
ഉണ്ണിയുടെ
രമേശ്യുടെ
```

Comment: Note that `.*?xxx` is the same as just `xxx`. That makes us doubt whether the OP needs regexes altogether - maybe simple `in` would do the trick. Although the title says "same ending", so it should be `endswith` or `xxx$` to stay on the re track.

Comment: @georg I have added a look ahead to ensure that the word ends with `യുടെ`

Answer (score 1):

You're matching every character that's not one of `യുടെ` and replacing that character with the empty string.  Therefore, of course, **only** occurrences of each of the characters in `യുടെ` can possibly remain in the resulting string!

The pattern `[^യുടെ]` means "any single character **except** those listed after the caret", which in this context means "not".  You mention "ending" in the Q's subject, but that has nothing to do with the pattern you're actually using.

Besides I'm perplexed at why you expect several lines of output when you're turning the list (confusingly named `string`!-) into a single string all on one line.  Once you get the pattern right you'd better apply it to each item of the list in a `for` loop or list comprehension.

Comment: Is it possible to change the code further so that I can achieve same  result

Answer (score 0):

You are greatly misunderstanding how regular expressions work `[]` square brackets declare a set of characters to match. When you use `^` at the start of a character class it declares a negative character class which matches any character *not* in the set. However, it says nothing about a sequence of characters.

I can't read the script you are using, but I see you have two different characters. I'll call the first character `A` and the second character `B`. Since you are using `re.sub`, you are replacing any character that is not `A` or `B` with the empty string. This leaves you with only the characters `A` and `B` in the string, which is the opposite of what you said that you wanted.

Also converting your list of strings into a single string by using the `str` function just doesn't make any sense. This essentially pretty prints your list including the square brackets.